# How to get the value of Preprocessor constant at runtime in ASP.NET / C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have

```
<%@ Page CompilerOptions="/d:QUUX" %>
```

how can I test QUUX constant in my C# Code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
#if QUUX
//some stuff here
#endif
```

you can find out more about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx43has(VS.80).aspx

If you want it at runtime then be creative with your precompiled stuff.

```
bool quux;

#if QUUX
quux = true;
#endif


if(quux) 
{
//do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler option /d is equivalent to the C# preprocessor option

```
#define symbol
```

You can check whether the symbol is defined by using

```
#if symbol
... code if symbol is defined 
#else
... code if symbol is undefined 
#endif
```

see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx).

Comment: Hi I know this, I want to access the value of this constant at RUNTIME.

Comment: @user284523 this is a compiler symbol, not a C# constant, and it does not have a value!

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly test for QUUX at runtime, as preprocessor directives are an entirely compile-time construct. You can set a variable inside an `#if` block & check that, but you can't directly test preprocessor flags.